# <C-tab> in Emacs 24.2 in Windows inserts character

Tags: windows-7, emacs, emacsw32

I'm using Emacs 24.2 under Windows 7 x64 with cedet, semantic, autocomplete and other modules.

In one of my config files I've defined

`(global-set-key (kbd "<C-tab>") 'semantic-complete-self-insert)`

But actually in Emacs when I type Ctrl+Tab it inserts some character (like japanese).

Also I have `(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)`. Can anybody explain this issue? (no problems with same configs under linux)

Answer (score 1):

Here is where to start: `C-h k C-TAB`.  And even `C-h k TAB` --- that is, ask Emacs what key sequence it sees when you hit the `Tab` key.

My guess is that it will say `TAB` and not `<tab>`. Different keyboards send different events when you hit the keyboard `Tab` key.  If `C-h k TAB` says it is `TAB`, then do this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'semantic-complete-self-insert)
```

You can also do this, which takes care of everything --- no need to actually find out what even the keyboard `Tab` key corresponds to:

```
M-x global-set-key RET TAB semantic-complete-self-insert RET
```

That is, hit the `Tab` key at the prompt from comand `global-set-key`.